# Why can't I add a text input to my notification and how would I set the keyboard type?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 running android version 6.0.1 and I'm following the example in the android developer documentation for adding an inline reply action to my notification. But not only is it not working for me, I'm not sure how I would go about changing the keyboard type to be numberDecimal for this inline response.

Instead of an inline text box in my notification, I'm seeing just a normal icon and corresponding label being attached below the normal content of the notification. Here's what I've tried:

```
Intent actualAmountIntent = new Intent(context, ActualAmountReceiver.class);
actualAmountIntent.putExtra("expenseId", expense.id);
PendingIntent actualAmountPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actualAmountIntent, 0);
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(ActualAmountReceiver.ACTUAL_AMOUNT_KEY)
        .setLabel(context.getString(R.string.actual_amount))
        .build();
Notification.Action action =
    new Notification.Action.Builder(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.add_icon),
        context.getString(R.string.actual_amount), actualAmountPendingIntent)
            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
            .build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(expense.name)
    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.scheduled_expense_notification))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_app_icon)
    .addAction(action)
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
notificationManager.notify((int)expense.id, builder.build());
```

ActualAmountReceiver.java:

```
package my.app.package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ActualAmountReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTUAL_AMOUNT_KEY = "actualAmount";

    MyDbHelper dbHelper;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        dbHelper = new MyDbHelper(context);
        Expense scheduledExpense = dbHelper.getExpense(intent.getLongExtra("expenseId", -1L));
        Float actualAmount = intent.getFloatExtra(ACTUAL_AMOUNT_KEY, -1.0f);

        System.out.println("actual amount received id(" + scheduledExpense.id + ") " +
                           "name(" + scheduledExpense.name + ") " +
                           "type(" + scheduledExpense.type + ") " +
                           "amount(" + amount + ")");

        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline reply works on Android 7.0 Nougat. As you mentioned you have Marshmallow in your device, it won't work.

Comment: Oh really? Ah, ok, that would make sense. But I can reply to text messages via the Samsung messenger app's notifications in 6.01, so is there a different 6.0.1 way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps they're using a fragment? Can a fragment be made to resemble a notification? For example the user would click my notification, and then the content intent would open a fragment on just the top of the screen that makes it look like the notification has expanded...

Comment: If I got it right, you meant that it will close the notification panel and a fragment pop up will open like WhatsApp app does below Nougat. Then it's achievable.